# jQuery idangerous swipper plugin: error in selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, swiper.js

I want to enable the swiper for touch devices to change pictures on my galleries:

The galleries markup is like this:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="http://localhost:8104/files/pic-spa-01.jpg" data-rel="gallery-1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8104/files/pic-spa-01-750x750.jpg')"></a>
    <a href="http://localhost:8104/files/pic-spa-02.jpg" data-rel="gallery-1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8104/files/pic-spa-02-750x750.jpg')"></a>
</div>
```

And I am trying like this:

```
if ( Modrnizer.touch ) {
            $.getScript(base_url + "/js/idangerous.swiper-2.1.min.js?p1", function () {

                //Main Swiper
                swiper = new Swiper('.gallery', {
                    onSlideChangeStart: function(){

                    }
                });

            })
}
```

But I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

And as there are more than one `.gallery` instances I tried:

```
$.getScript(base_url + "js/idangerous.swiper-2.1.min.js?p1", function () {
    //Main Swiper
    swiper = new Swiper('.gallery:eq(0)', {
        onSlideChangeStart: function(){

        }
    });
})
```

but then the error becomes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined VM1007:47
```

So anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

In this fiddle I even get a different error..

http://jsfiddle.net/9VBha/118/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep required Swiper's HTML structure:

```
<div class="swiper-container gallery">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="http://localhost:8104/files/pic-spa-01.jpg" data-rel="gallery-1" style="background-image: url('http://localhost:8104/files/pic-spa-01-750x750.jpg')"></a></div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't have access to HTML you convert it by script before Swiper init, something like:

```
$('.gallery').addClass('swiper-container');
$('.gallery').wrapInner('<div class="swiper-wrapper"></div>');
$('.gallery a').wrap('<div class="swiper-slide"></div>');
```

Comment: Thanks... bummer.. I have no acces to the `html` code... no workaround? thanks!